# How to hide all files of a certain extension?

Tags: windows-10, backup, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++, and the way it does auto backups without saving is through creating backup files whose extension is .bak. Fine and dandy, except if I have lots of files, my desktop gets cluttered pretty quickly with these files.

How can I make Windows 10 automatically hide all files whose extension is .bak? I understand that there exist [methods to automate Windows to do this with a program](https://superuser.com/a/346809/1675420). But how can I have Windows 10 hide all such files natively? After all, Windows is capable of hiding file extensions, and it can show or hide hidden files. Can the same be said for files ending with an extension like .bak?

Comment: Why are you saving files on your desktop?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you think no one saves files on their desktop, I have a surprise for you.

Comment: Many people do, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea ...

Comment: You cannot. But you can set them all as hidden (or write a program that does that). Or save them all in one location and hide that folder.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Gantendo!

Answer (score 1):

Windows has no automatic way of hiding files with a certain extension.

To hide all visible `.bak` files whenever you find that there are too
of them, create a `.bat` file on your desktop containing the following line:

```
attrib +h *.bak
```

Now whenever you wish to hide those `.bak` files, just double-click
on this `.bat` file and they will be hidden away.

You may also create a scheduled task that periodically runs this `.bat`,
to avoid the need for doing the above.

Note that hiding these files, you may not be aware when too many of them
accumulate in the desktop folder.
Also, if Notepad++ needs to access such a file for recovery in case
of a crash, it remains to be tested if it can see these hidden files,
or if hiding them effectively disables recovery.